# Using C sscanf to parse number from a directory path

Tags: c, parsing, scanf

I have the following string

```
/foo123/bar123/card45/foofoo/1.3/
```

And I want to parse the number that follows the word "card", which in the example above would be 45.  Should I use sscanf for this and if so, how would I go about doing so?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> Should I use `sscanf` for [XYZ problem]

**No.**

But you can use `strstr` and `strtol` instead:

```
const char *s = "/foo123/bar123/card45/foofoo/1.3/";
const char *p = "card";
const char *t = strstr(s, p);

int i = -1; // a negative number indicates a parse failure, for example
if (t != NULL) {
    t += strlen(p);
    char *end;
    i = strtol(t, &end, 10);
    if (!end || *end != '/') {
        // parsing the number failed
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `strstr()` followed by `sscanf()` will do the job. Suppose you have your source string in the character array `source_string`.Then use this:

```
char * ptr;
ptr = strstr(source_string,"card");

sscanf (ptr,"%*s %d",&number);  //Sorry this is wrong!!
sscanf(ptr,"card%d",&number);   //This is right!!
sscanf(ptr,"%*4s%d",&number);   //This works too


printf("The card number is %d",number);
```

`strstr()` gets you the address where "card" begins.Then you pass that address to `sscanf()` as the source.The `%*s` reads "card" but then discards it.After this the `%d` reads the number following "card" and stores it in the integer variable `number`, which you then display using the `printf()`.

Comment: this also works. i just had to change the format to `%*[^0-9]%d` since there was no space between card and the number.

Comment: @user2077092 I am sorry, there was a silly bug in my code which i was about to change when I saw your comment.You see the `%*s` will read and ignore everything beginning after "card".So see the new edit.

Answer (score 0):

How about using simple splitting function that cuts out your path by '/'?

Here is function that I use to split random char array by specific letter. It saves each parsed part into string vector.

```
vector<string> split(const char *str, char c)

{
    vector<string> result;

    while(1)
    {
        const char *begin = str;

        while(*str != c && *str)
                str++;

        result.push_back(string(begin, str));

        if(0 == *str++)
                break;
    }

    return result;
}
```

So, you can call this function like this

```
vector<string> ParsedString;
ParsedString = split("Your/Random/path", '/');
```

Then, you can access to each index of ParsedString to see any of them has specific word that you are looking for.

Or, if the word that you are looking for is always located on 3rd or 4th from front, then you can only pick that one for searching.

```
string InterestedTarget = ParsedString[4];
```

Comment: The question is tagged `c`, not `c++`.